# isDigit() returning true for letter

Tags: java, wrapper, character

When running the following program and inputing a letter, one of the output windows says that the letter is a digit when it is clearly not. Why?

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 * This program demonstrates some of the Character
 * class's character testing methods
 * 
 *
 */
public class CharacterTest {

public static void main(String[] args){
    String input;   //To hold the user's input
    char ch;    //To hold a single character

    //Get a character from the user and store
    //it in the ch variable
    input=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter "+
            "any single character.");

    ch= input.charAt(0);

    //Test the character
    if(Character.isLetter(ch)){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This is a letter.");
    }

    if(Character.isDigit(ch));{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thit is a digit.");
    }

    if(Character.isLowerCase(ch)){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "That is a lowercase"+
                " letter");
    }

    if(Character.isUpperCase(ch)){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "That is an uppercase"+
                " letter");
    }

    if(Character.isSpaceChar(ch)){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "That is an uppercase"+
                " letter");
    }

    if(Character.isWhitespace(ch)){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "That is an uppercase"+
                " letter");
    }

    System.exit(0);

}
}
```

Comment: You did not actually include a question in your post for people to respond to.

Comment: Nor you an answer but nobody's picking on you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if(Character.isDigit(ch));{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thit is a digit.");
    }
```

That means:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thit is a digit.");
```

without any condition, so it will always print that it's a digit.

By the way, neither spaces nor white spaces (funny how Java distinguishes between the two) are "uppercase letters".

Comment: In other words, careful where you put your semicolons.

Comment: Nice catch. I was wondering how one avoids this from happening. I suppose any good IDE would draw attention to such a construct.

Comment: And that's why Eclipse is *not* a good IDE, nor Java a good compiler (whereas other compilers would give a warning for this).

Comment: In other words use the code formtter in your IDE. This will help you avoid formatting which is misleading.

Comment: @Blindy, Java isn't a compiler, `javac` (or `javac.exe`) is (if you meant Oracle's compiler). A "space char" and "whitespace" _are_ not the same, have a look at the API to see the difference, there's nothing funny about it. I'm pretty sure that Eclipse could be set up in such a way that it _does_ produce a warning about a mis-placed semi-colon. Saying Eclipse is not a good IDE for such a programmers mistake is just silly. It would be equally silly as saying that people who say a certain IDE is not good while that IDE is being used by 100 thousands of developers a day, are nincompoops.

Comment: A fair point in the first part of your comment, although we both know what I meant. And I have better reasons for both my statements :)

Comment: @Blindy, you may have good reasons, but all I read from your answer is that you branded Eclipse "not good" because of a trivial thing (which I'm sure is not an issue: Eclipse can surely produce a warning in case of the misplaced `;` (I'm no Eclipse user myself, so I can't be 100% sure)). You just didn't reveal your _good reasons_, so I can't comment on them. For the record: I liked your answer: a clear explanation of why it went wrong, I just didn't like your comment :)

Comment: @Blindy Most warnings that the IDE displays are warnings from the compiler, so if you think that this quite abstruse case which wouldn't happen if you used auto formatting should be handled, talk to the javac guys. And I have no got not the slightest idea what would make a java compiler good or bad - spec compliance seems to be pretty much the only important feature (well useful warnings, but then compare that to C compilers). Actually I think that neither IntelliJ nor Netbeans give warnings for that stuff either. Visual Studio for C++ also doesn't. So what "good" IDE are we talking about?

Comment: @Voo, note that Eclipse doesn't use `javac`, but their own compiler. But IDE's can spew a sh1t-load of warnings, up to misspelled camel-cased identifier names (at least, IntelliJ-IDEA can! :)). And you can easily set the warning-level in IntelliJ lower (or higher).

Comment: @Bart Ah yes you're right. Also I just checked and my eclipse does actually give a warning about if (bla) ;. And I only used IntelliJ a bit and without changing default settings so I'll believe you ;) Though I've never missed that warning in any IDE I've used and had to look it up, so you'll excuse me if I don't think that's important - wouldn't make it in my Top10 of useful Warnings at least :)